# Customizing SimpleWebrtc

Tags: javascript, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I'm using [simplewebrtc](https://simplewebrtc.com/) for my webrtc project.

1. Is there anyway I can mute another person's audio whenever I want and unmute it?
2. Is there anyway I can get the stream of a particular user in a room and not of the rest in the same room?

   ```
   window.onload = function(){

           var room = "2";


           // Create webrtc connection
           var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
               localVideoEl: 'publisher',
               remoteVideosEl: '',
               autoRequestMedia: true,
               log: true,
               debug: false,
               detectSpeakingEvents: true,
               autoAdjustMic: false
           });


           // we did not get access to the camera
           webrtc.on('localMediaError', function (err) {
           });


           // a peer video has been added
           webrtc.on('videoAdded', function (video, peer) {
               console.log('video added', peer);

               var remotes = document.getElementById('subscriber');

               if (remotes) {
                   var container = document.createElement('div');
                   container.className = 'videoContainer';
                   container.setAttribute('data-user', userType);
                   // $div.attr('data-user', streamUser.userType);
                   container.setAttribute('class', 'col-md-6 each-video'); 
                   container.id = 'container_' + webrtc.getDomId(peer);
                   container.appendChild(video);

                   remotes.appendChild(container);


               }
           });

           // a peer video has been removed

           // a peer video was removed
           webrtc.on('videoRemoved', function (video, peer) {
               console.log('video removed ', peer);
               var remotes = document.getElementById('subscriber');
               var el = document.getElementById(peer ? 'container_' + webrtc.getDomId(peer) : 'localScreenContainer');
               if (remotes && el) {
                   remotes.removeChild(el);
               }
           });



           // when it's ready and we have a room from url, join the call
           webrtc.on('readyToCall', function(){
               if(room) webrtc.joinRoom(room);
           });


           if(room){
               webrtc.createRoom(room, function(err, name){
                       if(err){
                           console.log(err);
                       }
                   });
           }



            }
   ```

I didn't find anything for my questions in their documentation. If it's possible, then it would be great!

Comment: You can finde more information on the muting part [here](https://simplewebrtc.com/notsosimple.html), scroll down to the **All about muting** section.

Comment: Or click [this link](https://simplewebrtc.com/notsosimple.html#mute) to go directly to the muting section ;-)

Comment: I checked out the muting. But I believe it's muting my own audio and not of the remote audio?

Comment: scroll down to the end of that section